# What is the behaviour of `std::future::then` when called more than once?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, future

According to the Concurrency TS, what should happen in the following code?

```
auto f0 = std::async([]{return 0;});
auto f1 = f0.then([](auto& f){ return f.get() + 10; });
auto f2 = f0.then([](auto& f){ if(!f.valid()) return; return f.get() + 10;});
```

By the time the third line of code is executed, `f0` already has a continuation, so, according to the TS, should `f0` throw an exception, abort the program, UB or has a different behaviour? It's unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future/then), it is undefined:

> Attach the continuation func to `*this`. The behavior is undefined if `*this` has no associated shared state (i.e., `valid() == false`).
>
> ...
>
> After this function returns, `valid()` is `false`.

Comment: no. it doesn't mean that. it talks about calling `then` when the future is empty, for example, if the future was moved to another future.

Comment: I don't follow. Once you attach the first continuation, `f1` will be valid, but `f0` will no longer be, so trying to attach a second continuation to it will cause UB.

Comment: @DavidHaim, the `valid()` returns false after you call `get()` for the first time https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get